# how to rewrite this Oracle query to use efficient CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c, with-statement

I have a query which I would like to improve by using `with` clause. I tried a variant which is below but I can only reduce a bit the cost. How can I rewrite the query that the main part of the joins is done only once with a with clause keeping in mind that for the second subset I have this additional filter `AND WS.CODE ='S_WLM_WL_013'` ?

Any ideas would be really appreciated.

The query is

```
SELECT
CASE
WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(*)
      FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING GCO
        INNER JOIN EXIM1B.ALERT_HEADER AH
      ON AH.AT_ID=GCO.WLM_TRANSACTION_ID
  INNER JOIN EXIM1B.WORKFLOW_STATUSES WS
  ON AH.WW_STATUS_CODE    =WS.CODE
  WHERE GCO.MESSAGE_ID    =:1
  AND GCO.IDENTIFICATOR_ID=
    (SELECT MIN(IDENTIFICATOR_ID)
    FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING
    WHERE MESSAGE_ID=:1
    )
    )  =
  (SELECT COUNT(*)
  FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING GCO
  INNER JOIN EXIM1B.ALERT_HEADER AH
  ON AH.AT_ID=GCO.WLM_TRANSACTION_ID
  INNER JOIN EXIM1B.WORKFLOW_STATUSES WS
  ON AH.WW_STATUS_CODE    =WS.CODE
  AND WS.CODE             ='S_WLM_WL_013'
  WHERE GCO.MESSAGE_ID    =:1
  AND GCO.IDENTIFICATOR_ID=
    (SELECT MIN(IDENTIFICATOR_ID)
    FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING
    WHERE MESSAGE_ID=:1
    )
  )
THEN 'OK'
ELSE null  END AS StatusAlert FROM DUAL
```

I tried this one

```
with t as ( SELECT MIN(IDENTIFICATOR_ID) as minval , message_id FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING WHERE MESSAGE_ID=:1 group by message_id ) 
SELECT
  CASE
    WHEN ( SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING GCO inner join t on t.message_id = gco.message_id 
            INNER JOIN EXIM1B.ALERT_HEADER AH
           ON AH.AT_ID=GCO.WLM_TRANSACTION_ID
            INNER JOIN EXIM1B.WORKFLOW_STATUSES WS
           ON AH.WW_STATUS_CODE    =WS.CODE
          WHERE GCO.MESSAGE_ID    =:1
          AND GCO.IDENTIFICATOR_ID = t.minval 
         )  =
       (SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING GCO inner join t on t.message_id = gco.message_id 
       INNER JOIN EXIM1B.ALERT_HEADER AH
       ON AH.AT_ID=GCO.WLM_TRANSACTION_ID
       INNER JOIN EXIM1B.WORKFLOW_STATUSES WS
       ON AH.WW_STATUS_CODE    =WS.CODE
       AND WS.CODE             ='S_WLM_WL_013'
       WHERE GCO.MESSAGE_ID    =:1
       AND GCO.IDENTIFICATOR_ID = t.minval
      )
    THEN 'OK'
    ELSE null  END AS StatusAlert FROM DUAL
```

Comment: Have you already tried with `/*+ materialize */` hint ?

Comment: @Sujitmohanty30, I tried that, but it did not work

Comment: Please share your indexes. Do you have permissions to create indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reduce the cost calculating filtered and unfiltered statuses in the same query:

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN WS.CODE='S_WLM_WL_013' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 'OK' ELSE NULL END AS StatusAlert 
        FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING GCO
        INNER JOIN EXIM1B.ALERT_HEADER AH ON AH.AT_ID = GCO.WLM_TRANSACTION_ID
        INNER JOIN EXIM1B.WORKFLOW_STATUSES WS ON AH.WW_STATUS_CODE = WS.CODE
        WHERE GCO.MESSAGE_ID = :1
            AND GCO.IDENTIFICATOR_ID = (
                SELECT MIN(IDENTIFICATOR_ID)
                FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING
                WHERE MESSAGE_ID = :1
            )
FROM DUAL
```

**EDIT**

You can reduce further the cost of the query excluding the `JOIN` on the `WORKFLOW_STATUSES` table and filtering directly `EXIM1B.ALERT_HEADER.WW_STATUS_CODE`

```
SELECT CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = SUM(CASE WHEN /* WS.CODE */WW_STATUS_CODE='S_WLM_WL_013' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) THEN 'OK' ELSE NULL END AS StatusAlert 
        FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING GCO
        INNER JOIN EXIM1B.ALERT_HEADER AH ON AH.AT_ID = GCO.WLM_TRANSACTION_ID
        /* EXIM1B.WORKFLOW_STATUSES NOT NEEDED */
        /* INNER JOIN EXIM1B.WORKFLOW_STATUSES WS ON AH.WW_STATUS_CODE = WS.CODE */
        WHERE GCO.MESSAGE_ID = :1
            AND GCO.IDENTIFICATOR_ID = (
                SELECT MIN(IDENTIFICATOR_ID)
                FROM EXIM1B.GER_CUSTOMER_ONBOARDING
                WHERE MESSAGE_ID = :1
            )
FROM DUAL
```

Comment: thank you for your suggestion, but that query does not work. ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended for line 12. I guess that I have to remove the last line in your answer, then it works.

Comment: You are right, I have corrected the query, try it now. it is difficult without test data

Comment: thank you. I though that was the problem so actually I tested it and it works. The other answer also works, but I think yours is more elegant and also with a lower estimation cost.

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez, Join is preferred solution always but I am asking for my knowledge only. When you say about estimation cost, may I know in which part exactly the estimation varies ?

Answer (score 1):

Could you try with below,

```
WITH customer_onboarding 
AS
(SELECT /*+ materialize */ 
       gco.wlm_transaction_id
  FROM exim1b.ger_customer_onboarding gco
WHERE  gco.message_id = :1
  AND    gco.identificator_id = (SELECT MIN(identificator_id) 
                                   FROM exim1b.ger_customer_onboarding 
                                  WHERE message_id = :1)),
wrk_flw_not_filtered
AS
(SELECT /*+ materialize */
       ws.code,count(*) over () as cnt_not_filtered
  FROM customer_onboarding gco
  JOIN exim1b.alert_header ah
    ON ah.at_id = gco.wlm_transaction_id
  JOIN exim1b.workflow_statuses ws
    ON ah.ww_status_code = ws.code)
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN max(cnt_not_filtered) = count(*) 
         THEN 'OK'
        END statusalert
   FROM wrk_flw_not_filtered flt
  WHERE flt.code = 'S_WLM_WL_013';
```

Comment: thank you for the try, but it does not work: ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

Comment: @Roberto Hernandez, I updated my answer and used `max` as it would be same without any filter and remove `else` part of `case statement` as it will anyway give null in case count doesn't match, Could you check as last try ?

Comment: Now it works, and it materialises the result. I need to check whether the output is the same as in the original query, though. I upvote your answer. Thank you

Comment: Good to hear that. wish you find a good result afterwards. :)